# is it possible to automatically trace javascript function calls in ie10

Tags: javascript, html

At work I am modifying a CGI script written by someone else who no longer works for the company. Much of the work of managing the input form fields is done dynamically using javascript. I was wondering if there is any way for me to automatically trace javascript function calls. It would be ideal if something could display data in the console log of the developers tool.

My laptop is windows 7 using ie 10. The web server is Apache running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer console in IE to trace your javascript - heres a link to the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx